# Are the documented conditions accurate for SetForegroundWindow?

Tags: winapi

Refer to [the MSDN documentation for `SetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx)

Windows intentionally refuses many requests to set a particular window to foreground, with the stated goal that:

> An application cannot force a window to the foreground while the user is working with another window.

The conditions under which `SetForegroundWindow` will succeed are documented as:

> The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A process can set the foreground window only if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The process is the foreground process.
> - The process was started by the foreground process.
> - The process received the last input event.
> - There is no foreground process.
> - The process is being debugged.
> - The foreground process is not a Modern Application or the Start Screen.
> - The foreground is not locked (see `LockSetForegroundWindow`).
> - The foreground lock time-out has expired (see `SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT` in `SystemParametersInfo`).
> - No menus are active.

This documentation does not sound correct.  I believe that it started as a shorter list, in which only one of the conditions needed to be met.  But the actual behavior is more complex.

Can anyone confirm the actual behavior?  Is it:

> A process can set the foreground window only if all the following hold:
>
> - One or more of the following conditions is true:
>
>   - The process is the foreground process.
>   - The process was started by the foreground process.
>   - The process was identified in an `AllowSetForegroundWindow` call made by the foreground process
>   - The process received the last input event.
>   - There is no foreground process.
>   - The process is being debugged.
> - The foreground process is not a Modern Application or the Start Screen.
> - One of the following two conditions is true:
>
>   - The foreground is not locked (see `LockSetForegroundWindow`).
>   - The foreground lock time-out has expired (see `SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT` in `SystemParametersInfo`).
> - No menus are active.

If other experts concur that the documentation is erroneous here, I will file a bug report on Connect referencing this question.

Comment: Was about the ask the same question. And yes, I'm pretty sure that those conditions are - in their current form as this list - bogus, simply due to the very last bullet point, which contradicts the whole concept.

Comment: *"The process received the last input event."* This appears to be correct for mouse and keyboard input. It seems, though, that touch input is handled differently (at least on Windows 7), and it doesn't immediately qualify a process for setting the foreground window. Apparently, a process can only set the foreground window, once the accompanying mouse input event has been synthesized by the system. Can anyone confirm this?